# Delphi XE7 - Livebindings with multiselect ListBox

Tags: delphi, listbox, livebindings

please how to create store more items in multiselect listbox to database using livebindings?

For fill Listbox i used bind Item.Text & Item.LookupData. And now how to store multiple items to mssql database.

Thanks all :-) btw sorry my strong english :-)